How to use LdrInitShimEngineDynamic()?
How to use LdrInitShimEngineDynamic() in my own application so some function in my .exe is notified when DLLs are dynamically loaded into my process by me with LoadLibrary(), etc... or by someone else using CreateRemoteThread() etc... ?
Especially BEFORE the DllMain() and the DLL's entry point are executed and AFTER the DLL's base relocations and imports are resolved.
Also, does this catch DLL load events in the entire system or only in my process ?
This is how the NT Loader's calls progress in Win7 x64:
LoadLibraryExW()
LdrLoadDll()
LdrpLoadDll()
LdrpLoadDllInternal()
LdrpProcessWork()
LdrpMapDllFullPath()
LdrpMapDllNtfileName()
LdrpMapDllWithSectionHandle()
LdrpMinimalMapModule()
LdrpMapViewOfSection()
LdrpCompleteMapModule()
LdrpRelocateImage()
LdrpProtectAndRelocateImage();
LdrpSetProtection()
LdrpRelocateImageWithBias()
LdrpProcessMappedModule()
LdrpCorProcessImports()    <-- LdrpSendDllNotifications() is called in there in Windows 7.
LdrpMapAndSnapDependency()    <-- DLL's imports are resolved here
LdrpPrepareImportAddressTableForSnap()
LdrpPrepareModuleForExecution()
LdrpInitializeGraphRecurse()
LdrpInitializeNode()
LdrpCallInitRoutine()    <-- Shims are called in there


why not use LdrRegisterDllNotification if you need only notification about dll load/unload ?

Because I thought that LdrRegisterDllNotification() does not notify BEFORE the DllMain() and the DLL's entry point are executed and AFTER the DLL's base relocations and imports are resolved.  Am I wrong ?

notification is called before dll entry point or tls callbacks executed

That's great !  ...but does the notification generated by LdrRegisterDllNotification() occur AFTER the DLL's base relocations and imports are resolved ?

yes, after import/reloc processed and before any code from dll is executed

simply passed hmod (single parameter in call LdrInitShimEngineDynamic) must export several api. ntdll resolve it and save. and call when need. however signature of this api can be changed. and only one shim per process

@RbMm:  Wait'a minute.  The documentation for LdrRegisterDllNotification() states: "This notification occurs before dynamic linking takes place."  See:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/ldrregisterdllnotification

i not write documentation, i simply say as is

@RbMm:  I think you are wrong.  These notifications are sent by LdrpSendDllNotifications() which is invoked in LdrpCorProcessImports()  and that is before the imports are resolved in LdrpMapAndSnapDependency(), see:
https://github.com/paskalian/WID_LoadLibrary/raw/main/Images/Diagram.svg

you think wrong. if i say, i know what i say. and you can easy check this by self. after LdrpSendDllNotifications LdrpDynamicShimModule is called and then LdrpInitializeGraphRecurse -> LdrpInitializeNode - > LdrpCallInitRoutine

Yeah, but the DLL's imports are resolved in LdrpMapAndSnapDependency() which occurs AFTER LdrpSendDllNotifications() is called.

no, again if i say, i know what i say. https://i.imgur.com/9ps0pNr.png

https://i.imgur.com/tsopXIj.png

Which version of Windows is that ?  I get something else. See the updated question

this is for all version. callback is called after import processed . why you can not write test and simply check this

implement callback and check from it dll IAT, etc. or take my debugger and build execute graph by self

I will write a test tomorrow (sleeping time in my time zone now).  Please check back here tomorrow

https://imgur.com/a/UBnSPRg

See the test at:  tinyurl.com/4RbMm123

and what i need to see ? you think i not test this by self ? i not use LdrRegisterDllNotification  before, many count of times ?

and as hint - if you need test import - print IAT.

I am printing the IAT entries pImportAddressTable->u1.Function in the function PrintImports(). If you do NOT use a pre-bound x64 DLL as the input, you will see that after the notification fires, the function's address is not in the pImportAddressTable->u1.Function, ...only the RVA to the name is there. However after the LoadLibrary() returns/finishes, the function's address is written into it.  What output do you get?

i got correct output of course. and not exist prebound dlls in windows, since ASLR used. you want say i mistake ?!?

I do not get pImportAddressTable->u1.Function != pImportNameTable->u1.AddressOfData  on NOT pre-bound DLLs in Windows7 x64 until LoadLibrary() returns/finishes.  What version of Windows do you use?  Please show me your output.

i long time use win 11/10/8.1 even dont remember when i run win7 last time. https://pastebin.com/G1R9izGH

on win7 really before import resolved. but begin from win 8.1 (or 8) - https://imgur.com/a/jjONYIB (7 and 8) anyway win7 already very long time not actual.

So Win7 calls the DLL load notification BEFORE the imports are resolved and Win 8.1 calls this notification AFTER the imports are resolved. However this question is not about the LdrRegisterDllNotification() but about the LdrInitShimEngineDynamic() so lets continue this discussion at the following address:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79106057/since-when-have-the-notifications-registered-by-ldrregisterdllnotificatio
